# Fill combox 2 according to combobox 1

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, combobox

I have 2 ComboBox. But I need combo_type to be updated according to the value of combo_maker.

I tried to make a ComboSelected but it was a failure.

When combobox_maker I selected any values. There are no change in combobox_type. I tried few codes change but nothing.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import configparser
import tkinter
import tkinter
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

Product = Tk()
Product.title ('App - Add Product')
Product.geometry("800x600")
#CONNECT DB
def connect_db():
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read('config.ini')
        return mysql.connector.connect(host = config['mysql']['host'],
                                        port = config['mysql']['port'],
                                        user = config['mysql']['database_user'],
                                        passwd = config['mysql']['database_password'],
                                        db = config['mysql']['database_name'])
#CONNECT DB

#COMBO MAKER
def combo_input_maker():#<--Populate combo_maker
    conn = connect_db()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT maker_name FROM makers")
    result=cursor.fetchall()
    return result
#COMBO MAKER

#COMBO TYPE
def combo_input_type():#<--Populate combo_type
    conn = connect_db()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    some_name = combo_maker.get()#<--Query with value select from combo_maker
    cursor.execute("SELECT t1.type FROM maker_types t1 INNER JOIN makers t2 ON t1.maker_id = t2.id WHERE maker_name =%s", [some_name])
    result=cursor.fetchall()
    return result
#COMBO TYPE

combo_maker = ttk.Combobox(Product,state="readonly")
combo_maker['value'] = [item for result in combo_input_maker() for item in result if item]
combo_maker.current(0)
combo_maker.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_input_type())#<--When ComboboxSelected in combo_maker, call def combo_input_type()
combo_maker.place(x=5, y=5, height = 25, width = 180)

combo_type = ttk.Combobox(Product,state="readonly")
combo_type['value'] = [item for result in combo_input_type() for item in result if item]
combo_type.current(0)
combo_type.place(x=200, y=5, height = 25, width = 180)

Product.mainloop()
```

No change in combo_type when combo_maker change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issues are that:

1. you wrongly initialize `combo_maker`;
2. you pass the result of
       `comb_input_type()` instead of function reference of
       `comb_input_type` in `combo_make.bind(...)`.

Below are the modified code based on yours:

```
#COMBO MAKER
def combo_input_maker():#<--Populate combo_maker
    # use global cursor instead of local one
    cursor.execute("SELECT maker_name FROM makers")
    result=[rec[0] for rec in cursor]
    return result
#COMBO MAKER

#COMBO TYPE
def combo_input_type(event=None):#<--Populate combo_type
    some_name = combo_maker.get()#<--Query with value select from combo_maker
    # use global cursor
    cursor.execute("SELECT t1.type FROM maker_types t1 INNER JOIN makers t2 ON t1.maker_id = t2.id WHERE maker_name = %s", [some_name])
    result = [rec[0] for rec in cursor]
    # populate combo_type
    combo_type['value'] = result
    combo_type.current(0)
    return result
#COMBO TYPE

# connect DB once
conn = connect_db()
cursor = conn.cursor()

combo_maker = ttk.Combobox(Product,state="readonly")
combo_maker['value'] = combo_input_maker() #[item for result in combo_input_maker() for item in result if item]
combo_maker.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_input_type) # use function reference here
combo_maker.place(x=5, y=5, height = 25, width = 180)

combo_type = ttk.Combobox(Product,state="readonly")
combo_type.place(x=200, y=5, height = 25, width = 180)
```

Comment: Something as wrong with ```combo_maker['value']```. I have the values but with {}. Like {test 1}, {test2}.It's only 'test 1' without {}. And maybe for that combo_type doesn't work.

Comment: I think first the combobox value be flatten for result. In one of my previous post is why ```combo_maker = ttk.Combobox(Product,value=[item for result in combo_input_maker() for item in result if item],state="readonly") ```

Comment: Since there are spaces in the result, you need to populate the result using list comprehension: `result=[rec[0] for rec in cursor]` in `combo_input_maker()`.  Similar to that in `combo_input_type()` as well.

Comment: some_name is [some_name] in the query. I want to edit. But they are already around. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't run your code since you are pulling data from a DB, but normally you can create `dict` for this. Below is a simple sample.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

dic = {"A": ["Apple","Orange"],
       "B": ["Pineapple","Banana"],
       "C": ["Watermelon","Kiwi"]}

def on_select(event):
    b_box["values"] = dic[a_box.get()] #modify 2nd combobox directly
    b_box.current(0)

a_box = ttk.Combobox(root,value=[k for k in dic],state="readonly")
a_box.pack()
b_box = ttk.Combobox(root,state="readonly")
b_box.pack()

a_box.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",on_select)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Works fine with ```dic```.But i have the same issue with {} in the values