# What am I wrong with the Python code? Combobox1 does not open Combobox2 from database

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, tkinter

I ran the instructions from [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55964708/fill-combox-2-according-to-combobox-1). Credo di aver fatto tutto (o quasi) correttamente. I cannot understand what is wrong. No error in console/terminal. The problem is that the Combobox2 remains empty, after selecting the Combobox1.

Why does the combobox2 (City) remain empty, when I select a nation in combobox1 (Nation)? I would like the different names of each city for each selected nation to appear in combobox2 Thank you

```
con = sqlite3.connect('/home/mypc/Scrivania/xxxx/Database.db')
cursor = con.cursor()

### NATION COMBOBOX ###
def combo_nation():
cursor.execute('SELECT Nation FROM Table')
result=[rec[0] for rec in cursor]
return result

### CITY COMBOBOX ###
def combo_city(event=None):
cursor.execute('SELECT City FROM Table WHERE Nation')
result = [rec[0] for rec in cursor]
city['value'] = result
city.current(0)
return result

nation=ttk.Combobox(window,state="readonly")
nation['value'] = combo_nation()
nation.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_city)
nation.place(x=5, y=150,height = 25, width = 180)

city=ttk.Combobox(window,state="readonly")
city.place(x=5, y=180, height = 25, width = 180)
```

Example: Single Table (Database)
I don't want to set a specific country in SQL. I want them all to go out and then the cities change according to the chosen Nation. I want all the Nations to come out in Combobox1, and in Combobox2 the various cities related to each Nation.

[image]

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal to see error messsages?

Comment: Yes. No mistakes. No error in console/terminal. The problem is that the Combobox2 remains empty ... after selecting the Combobox1

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which line of code is executed and what you get in variabales. Maybe function is never executed, or maybe you have wrong SQL query.

Comment: `WHERE Nation` doesn't look good for me - it may gives empty result. It should be something like `WHERE Nation = "France"` which means something like `execute('SELECT City FROM Table WHERE Nation = ?', event)`

Comment: I don't want to set a specific country. I want them all to go out and then the cities change according to the chosen Nation. I want all the Nations to come out in Combobox1, and in Combobox2 the various cities related to each Nation.

Comment: You have to use `?` in query and `execute` will put selected nation in this place.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand. I have recently been using Python. Can you write a response with the code? Thank you

Comment: You have code in @acw1668 answer. I would write exactly the same code.

Comment: No. The "?" after SELECT City FROM Table1 WHERE Nation ... that's not right. I need to select all the cities of a chosen nation (among many) in the Combobox Nation. I don't want to set a specific country or city. What should I write in place of "?" in SQL?

Comment: as I said before - put NOTHING - `?` is special char which `execute()` will use to put value from variable `val` and you have to do NOTHING. It is special method to create safe query.

Comment: Yes, I just read from the other kind user. I did not know. I thought it was his way of telling me to write a particular nation. Excuse me. Now everything works. Thanks to you too for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are issues in your SQL statements:

```py
### NATION COMBOBOX ###
def combo_nation():
    # use DISTINCT
    cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT Nation FROM Table1')
    result = [rec[0] for rec in cursor]
    return result

### CITY COMBOBOX ###
def combo_city(event=None):
    # get selected nation
    val = nation.get()
    # get cities for selected nation
    cursor.execute('SELECT City FROM Table1 WHERE Nation = ?', (val,))
    result = [rec[0] for rec in cursor]
    city['value'] = result
    city.current(0)
    return result
```

Note that "Table" is not a valid table name, so I changed to "Table1" as an example.

Comment: I did not write anything after NATION, because I thought it was useless to specify a specific country. I want to make ANY Nation select in Combobox1, subsequently it will correspond to its cities in Combobox2 Table was just an example, I know it's not valid.The table in the photo is just an example. There are actually hundreds of countries and hundreds of cities. QUESTION: What should I write in place of your "?"

Comment: I want to get:
France > Paris, Strasbourg, Lille, Marsiglia, etc
Italy > Roma, Naples, etc
Spain > Madrid, Barcelona, Siviglia, etc

Comment: @GiovanniRusso You put nothing in place of `?` - `execute()` will put `val` in place `?` using special method to make safe query which can't steel other information (ie. passwords) from your database.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand. I've recently been using Python. Can you write me the code in the answer please? Thank you

Comment: @GiovanniRusso `?` is a *placeholder* which will be replaced by the arguments followed by the SQL statement.  Did you try my solution?

Comment: Aaaa ok, I thought it was your text to suggest that I had to set a specific country. I'm sorry. Anyway I tried the code. It still does not work. The Combobox2 City is still empty. There is still something wrong with the code

Comment: A little curiosity, considering that I copied the code from the link of another question. What does it mean  result = [rec[0] for rec in cursor]? What is Rec? What is it for? Thank you

Comment: @GiovanniRusso I would use name `row` instead of `rec` and then you will see that it gets values from first column in all selected rows. database usually return all results/rows as list - even if row has only one value - and then you have to convert nested list `[ ["Paris"], ["Lilli"], ...]` to flatten list `["Paris", "Lilli", ..]`

Comment: OK perfect. I understand now. Thanks for the code and all the answers. You have been very kind indeed. I appreciated.